# Server side filtering in syncfusion grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, grid, syncfusion

I have a syncfusion grid which has huge number of records. I have implemented server side paging using skip and take like this:

```
Data = learningEntities.Employees.Join(learningEntities.EmployeeAddressDetails,
                        o => o.Id, od => od.EmployeeId,
                        (o, od) => new
                        {
                            Id = o.Id,
                            FirstName = o.FirstName,
                            LastName = o.LastName,
                            EmployeeNumber = o.EmployeeNumber,
                            DateOfJoining = o.DateOfJoining,
                            City = od.City,
                            State = od.State,
                            Pin = od.Pin
                        }).ToList().Skip(dm.Skip).Take(dm.Take);
```

Now, I need to implement server side filtering before applying the paging. I am not able to find a way to handle filtering on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the below knowledge base to implement server side data operation.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/4300/